# Find a counterexample that the sequence $\{f(a_n)\}_n$ is bounded but not convergent

Tags: real-analysis

If  $f :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$  be   a  strictly increasing   continuous  function and $\{a_n\}$ is  a sequence   in $[0,1]$ , then find  a  counterexample   that  the  sequence $\{f(a_n)\}_n$ is bounded but not   convergent?

I take $f(x) = e^x$ but  this  is  not  bounded . Again  I take $f(x)= e^{-x}$  but this is  not  strictly  increasing.

I'm  not  able to find  a  counterexample   which satisfied the given statement.

Any hints/solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $a_n:=\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}$ and any strictly increasing function $f$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: ... or in fact any function $f$ with $f(0)\ne f(1)$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I agree. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

Define $a_n=1$ if $n$ is even and $a_n=0$ if $n$ is odd.